# Why does solving linear systems of equations with HHL return imaginary numbers?

Tags: hhl-algorithm, linear-algebra

The textbook shows an example system of linear equations $Ax=b$ with

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{1}{3} & 1 \\
1 & -\frac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix} \,\,\,\,
b=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The program in the text shows a result in real numbers. When trying to run a larger $A$ matrix and $b$ matrix, the output includes complex numbers even though the actual answer (calculated using numpy linear equation solver) shows no complex numbers. Where are these imaginary numbers coming from?

Comment: Without more details of the case you've tried, and the code you've run, it may be hard to track down. However, one quick thing to check - is it that your output $x$ is a real vector, but every element is multiplied by the same complex phase $e^{i\theta}$?

Comment: The code im running is the HHL code in the qiskit textbook, section 4A:Running HHL on a simulator (https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/hhl_tutorial.html). By replacing the matrix and vector: matrix = [[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], [-5, 5, 6, 6, 6, -1], [3, 6, 2, 8, 8, 4], [2, 5, -3, 2, 4, 3], [1, 3, 2, 3, -2, 3], [12, 7, 1, 3, 3, 2]] and vector = [2,1,-2,2,1,2], the output solution includes complex numbers.